# How to get values of vars by its name

Tags: java, cplex

I'm using the CPLEX Java interface to do some MIP problems, the optimizer is doing well but I can't get values of vars by their names.

The definitions of my vars are in a for loop, so in the outer code, I can't use `cplex.getValue()` function to get their values.
Please remind me of any methods that can get all the values or get values by their names.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
    // c1 is changing when i increase
    IloNumVar[] x = new IloNumVar[c1];
    for (int j = 0; j < c1; ++j) {
        x[j] = cplex.numVar(0, 1, IloNumVarType.Int, "x" + String.valueOf(i) + "_" + String.valueOf(j));
    }
} 
...
cplex.solve();
```

How to retrieve all x values outer for loop after cplex.solve()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't try to recover them by their names. Keep your CPLEX variables in lists, arrays, dictionaries, structures, class instances or whatever in your code. Your IloNumVars are just normal objects that can be stored like any other. In your example code, just keep those IloNumVar arrays in a structure declared outside the loop (e.g. a list of those IloNumVar[] arrays).

If you *really* need to retrieve them by name, then put them in a dictionary, keyed on the variable name - again that would have to be declared outside your loop above. But that would be less efficient than just keeping them in your usual Java data structures as it would require extra lookup processing inside the ictionary to find the item by name.